# Perform background HTML stuff and return the URL

Tags: java, android, html

Have no idea if this is possible since I just started coding android && have no experience with HTML.

But here it goes:
I have a user URL input. I then want the app to open the website in the background, find the search field on the site, type in a search string and have the URL that is generated upon submit returned to the app. Is that even possible?

Thinking that the HTML code for the website might contain some info about where the search box could be expected to be found.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it's possible, use AsyncTask